# Deploying to Elastic Beanstalk - can't find directories

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am pushing deploys to a new Beanstalk app and trying to run commands with a .config file:

```
// .ebextensions/composer.config
commands:                                                                       
  01wtf:                                                                        
    command: cd /var/app && ls
  02wtf:                                                                        
    command: cd /var/app/current && ls
```

`01wtf` returns

```
.
..
/current
/support
```

`02wtf` returns

```
.
..
```

I am trying to run commands on `/var/app/ondeck` (like all the blog posts and SO answers say) but **I can't find it on the disk!** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the `.config` file specifying `commands:`.

I should have been using `container_commands` (docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands)

My commands were running *before* the deployment phase; so, `ondeck` has not been created yet, and (in the case of a brand new ec2 instance) `current` was empty.

```
// .ebextensions/composer.config
container_commands:                                                                       
  01wtf:                                                                        
    command: cd /var/app && ls
  02wtf:                                                                        
    command: cd /var/app/current && ls
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.